# How to extract the file from the filepicker?

Tags: meteor, filepicker

I just use Filepicker to upload the picture. After I uploaded the picture I can get the url in the console.

```
 Template.uploadform.events
  'change #upload_widget': (evt) ->
    if console?
      console.log JSON.stringify(evt.fpfile)
```

Now I need to show that images to my web application by those url. I am just a new bie on meteor. I am using jade-handlebars and coffeescript in my application.
Pleas help me out how can I show the images by using that url in my application ???

Thank You in advance.!!!

Comment: The eventedmind.com episodes on file uploading might be useful to you. It starts here: https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/html5-introducing-the-file-api. It sounds like you're not trying to upload, but instead get a data-url you can use to show the image right away. The video above will still be helpful, but just readAsDataUrl instead of binary.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set a Session variable you can use to hold the url:
   `Session.setDefault('uploadedImageUrl', placeholderImageUrl)`
2. Once the image has been uploaded and you have it, set the session variable to the new url: `Session.set('uploadedImageUrl', fpImageUrl)`
3. Make a template helper to reference the session variable in your template: `Template.uploadform.uploadedImageUrl = -> Session.get('uploadedImageUrl')`
4. In your template, show the image like so: `img(src="{{uploadedImageUrl}}")`

Once the image has been uploaded, your placeholder image will be replaced with the new uploaded image.